# Reset the position of jwplayer controls?

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I need to redesign a jwplayer with new controls in new position for branding of some website. How can I do this?

Comment: You can make your own skin, but the controls will always be over the player.

Comment: There is one example link [blogtalkradio](http://blog.blogtalkradio.com/blogtalkradio/blogtalkradio-embeddable-player/) I want player like this.

Comment: This is just using a custom skin. You can make a custom skin using our SDK, which is available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/